# How to dynamically add clear button for each value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add clear button for each value and i would like to to delete the satisfy value/text from chain value.

```
<input id="value" />
<div id="show"></div>
```

```
$('#value').on('keyup input paste',  function(){
   var show=$(this).val().split(',').join('<br/>'); 
   $('#show').html(show); });
```

Output :

`demo1`
`demo2`

Need output :

`demo1  <a>clear_button1</a>`
`demo2  <a>clear_button2</a>`

When i click on each clear button i would like to remove satisfy value from the input.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<input id="value" />
<div id="show"></div>
<script>
$('#value').on('keyup input paste',  function(){
    var show=$(this).val().split(',');
    var temp="";

    for (i=0; i<show.length; i++)
    {
        if(show[i]!="")
        {
            temp += '<div><span>'+show[i]+'</span><a href="#" class="clear">clear</a></div>';
        }
    }
    $('#show').html(temp); 
});

$('#show').on('click','.clear',function(){
    Object.prototype.getKey = function( value ) {
    for( var p in this ) {
        if( this.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) {
             if( this[ p ] === value )
                 return p;
            }
        }
    }

    var val = $(this).parent().find('span').html();
    var temp =$("#value").val();
    temp = temp.split(',');
    temp = temp.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
    var k = temp.getKey(val);
    delete temp[k];
    temp = temp.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
    $("#value").val(temp);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $("#value").keyup();
});
</script>
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kupendra/ncvw4wz6/7/)

Comment: Interesting answer. +1 from me. One small issue I see is, when clearing a middle text, the comma is remaining.

Answer (score 0):

like this ?

```
   $('#value').on('keyup input paste',  function(){
   var show=$(this).val().split(',').join('<br/>'); 
   var btn="<a href='#' id='btn_"+this.id+"'>clear_button1</a>";
   $('#show').html(show+btn); 
   $('#btn_'+this.id).click(function(){
      $('#value').val('');
      $('#show').text('');
   })
  });
```

Comment: Closer but I would like for each value.